# How to check if task is terminated in Ada

Tags: ada

I have task `A` that calls task `B`.
At some pint task `B` is terminated but task `A` doesn't know that and calls now terminated task `B`.
Since task `B` is terminated calling it from task `A` terminates task `A`.

How can I check if task `B` is terminated from task `A`?

If it matters I am using GNAT Programming Studio.
I could make a global variable that is set by `B` before termination, but I would rather find out state of `B` from `A`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for B'Terminated, see [RM 9.9](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-9.html)

```
if not B'Terminated then
   -- do something
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses the 'Terminated attribute to allow the main task to determine when a set of tasks has completed.

```ada
------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Parallel Array Filling --
------------------------------------------------------------------
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;
with Ada.Calendar; use Ada.Calendar;

procedure Array_Fill is
   Start_Time : Time := Clock;
   Num_Tasks  : constant := 8;
   Slice_Size : constant Natural := 8_388_608;
   Max_Size   : constant Natural :=  Num_Tasks * Slice_Size -1;
   subtype Values is Natural range 0..10_000;

   type Big_Array is array(Natural range 0..Max_Size) of Integer;
   type Big_Access is access Big_Array;

   -- Instantiate the generic package Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random
   -- to produce random numbers in the range of the subtype Values
   -- defined above
   package Rand_Nums is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Values);
   use Rand_Nums;

   -- dynamically allocate the integer array, initializing all array
   -- elements to the lowest valid value for type Integer
   The_Array  : Big_Access := new Big_Array'(Others => Integer'First);

   task type Filler is
      -- Set_Low is a synchronization point between the main task and
      -- an instance of the task type Filler. This point allows the main
      -- task to send an integer value >= 0 directly to the Filler task
      Entry Set_Low(Item : in Natural);
   end Filler;

   task body Filler is
      Id         : Natural;
      Low_Index  : Natural;
      High_Index : Natural;
      Seed       : Generator;
   begin
      Reset(Seed);

      -- the Filler task waits for the main task to send a value to the
      -- entry Set_Low.
      accept Set_Low(Item : in Natural) do
         Id := Item;
      end Set_Low;

      Low_Index := Id * Slice_Size;
      High_Index := Low_Index + (Slice_Size - 1);

      for I in Low_Index..High_Index loop
         The_Array(I) := Random(Seed);
      end loop;
   end Filler;

   -- create an array type containing Num_Tasks of Filler tasks;
   type Task_List is array(Natural range 0..Num_tasks - 1) of Filler;

   -- Create an instance of the task array. The tasks start as soon
   -- as this array is created
   List       : Task_List;

begin -- begin the execution of the main task
   -- Send ID values to each instance of the Filler task in the array
   -- List.
   for I in Task_List'Range loop
      List(I).Set_Low(I);
   end loop;

   loop -- waits for all the tasks to terminate
      if List(0)'Terminated and then
        List(1)'Terminated and then
        List(2)'Terminated and then
        List(3)'Terminated and then
        List(4)'Terminated and then
        List(5)'Terminated and then
        List(6)'Terminated and then
        List(7)'Terminated then
         exit;  -- exit this loop
      end if;
   end loop;

   Put_Line("Elapsed time " & Duration'Image(Clock - Start_Time) & " seconds");
end Array_Fill;
```